# ImportError: cannot import name 'Flow' from partially initialized module 'firstapp.models.flows' (most likely due to a circular import), how to design

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, oop, django-models

I have a problem, probably in my design.
In my Django project I have a 'Flow' object with 'event_reason' field in it, Foreign key to 'Event' object, therefore I need to import Event object, (otherwise I get the error: `Cannot create form field for 'event_reason' yet, because its related model 'Event' has not been loaded yet`). Therefore my code of my models is (in models/flows.py)

```
from .events import Event
class Flow(models.Model): 
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)  
    flow_type = models.IntegerField(default=-1, choices=FLOW_CHOICES)          
    ...
    event_reason = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=None, related_name='events_flow',blank=True, null=True)

class FlowForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Flow
        fields = '__all__'
```

In addition I have 'amount' and 'flow_type' fields in the 'Flow' objects and I want that the 'post_save' signal will save a new Flow associated to this Event. Therefore the Event model code is (in models/events.py):

```
from .flows import Flow
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    flow_type = models.IntegerField(default=-1, choices=FLOW_CHOICES)
    
@receiver(post_save, sender=Event)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    new_flow = Flow.objects.create(...)
```

And I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'Flow' from partially initialized module 'firstapp.models.flows' (most likely due to a circular import)`

I understand that I cannot my a circular import but I want this functionality to work. How to solve this problem? Should I design the objects otherwise?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to import `Event` in `flows.py`? I see that you specify the foreign key using a string. Also signals are best not written in `models.py`. As to `Cannot create form field for 'event_reason' yet, because its related model 'Event' has not been loaded yet` why do you get this error? Where do you make your form and why does it appear to be made at the time of model generation?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I get `Cannot create form field for 'event_reason' yet, because its related model 'Event' has not been loaded yet` when I remove the import of `Event` in `flows.py`. I also thought I don't need this import but without the import I get this error and I'm not sure why. I would appreciate your help since I don't know what form is regarded. In addition where should I put the signals? Thank you

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat edited the question, added the form I have in `flows.py`. maybe this form is causing the problem? Thank you

Comment: You should not be making forms in the models file either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `models.py` should mostly only have model code, sometimes people do put signals (bad practice) but **forms** should absolutely not be written there.

One should write forms in `forms.py` so your should move that code to a separate file and import the model there. The **forms** etc. should not be imported in the models as their should be no need for them there.

So in `forms.py`:

```
from .models.flows import Flow


class FlowForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Flow
        fields = '__all__'

# Other forms also go here
```

Now for signals it is best not to write them in models as I said before. They should be written in some file let's say `signals.py` and this will be imported in the apps config classes `ready` method.

So in `signals.py`:

```
# imports

@receiver(post_save, sender=Event)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    new_flow = Flow.objects.create(...)
```

Now your app should have an app config by default in which you would add an import in the ready method. So in your apps `apps.py` just add an import in the ready method:

```
class YouAppConfig(AppConfig):
    # some attributes here don't change

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

Now remove those circular imports in your model files.

Comment: Changing the forms location solved my problem. Thank you